# Problema al crear una tabla con una llave foranea

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

resulta que estoy creando una base de datos, pero me sale un mensaje de error en el oracle que dice esto:

> ORA-02270: no hay ninguna clave única o primaria correspondiente para
>   esta lista de columnas
>   02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"

La verdad es que estoy empezando en esto y no tengo mucha idea de cómo podría arreglarlo, los creates són estos:

```
create table poblacion
(
    nom_po varchar2(20),
    nom_pa varchar2(20),
    constraint pobl_nom_po_pa_PK primary key (nom_po,nom_pa),
    constraint pobl_nom_pa_FK foreign key (nom_pa) references pais(nom_pa)
);
create table almacen
(
    cod number(5),
    nom_po_s varchar2(20),
    nom_pa_s varchar2(20),
    constraint alm_cod_PK primary key(cod),
    constraint alm_nom_po_pa_s_FK foreign key (nom_po_s,nom_pa_s) references poblacion(nom_po,nom_pa)
);
alter table almacen
add(
    nom_po_e varchar2(20),
    nom_pa_e varchar2(20),
    constraint alm_nom_po_pa_e_FK foreign key(nom_po_e,nom_pa_e) references almacen(nom_po_s,nom_pa_s)
);
```

Llevo un buen rato mirando a ver si encuentro el problema y no consigo verlo. 
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Estas referenciando con una FK a campos que no son unicos por lo que no te puede crear la relación

Comment: ¿Entonces a los campos nom_p_s y nom_pa_s tendría que poner "unique"? La idea es hacer una reflexiva con nom_po_e y nom_pa_e a nom_po_s y nom_pa_s

Comment: Yo creo que si, con poner unique te podria valer.

Comment: Lo he probado pero sigue saliendo lo mismo :(

Comment: Entonces creo que es necesario que los campos a los que apuntes sean clave.

Comment: Ok, perdón lo habia puesto mal. Ha funcionado!! Muchas gracias me has ayudado mucho.